# Homotopy in $\mathsf{Ch}_\bullet(R\mathsf{Mod})$ induced by homotopy in $\mathsf{Top}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

I'm trying to put together the relationships between homotopy in $\mathsf{Top}$, chain homotopy, and homotopy in $\mathsf{Ch}_\bullet(R\mathsf{Mod})$. I more-or-less understand the connection between the former two and between the latter two, but I don't understand whether a homotopy in $\mathsf{Top}$ naturally induces a homotopy in $\mathsf{Ch}_\bullet(R\mathsf{Mod})$.

I can use the explicit form of the chain homotopy in Hatcher's proof of the homotopy invariance of singular homology and obtain from it a homotopy in $\mathsf{Ch}_\bullet(R\mathsf{Mod})$. This 
$$\text{homotopy in }\mathsf{Top} \rightarrow \text{chain homotopy} \rightarrow \text{homotopy in }\mathsf{Ch}_\bullet$$ process, while getting me what I want, leaves me hoping for a better alternative - the homotopy I get seems contrived because of all the games with simplices.

Is there any simpler homotopy on $\mathsf{Ch}_\bullet$ induced by a homotopy in $\mathsf{Top}$? Perhaps it has a simpler form?

**Edit:** I should clarify I'm looking for an induced homotopy in the sense of abstract homotopy theory, i.e in the sense of cylinder objects. I want an simple, intuitive, abstract homotopy $\phi:f_\sharp \simeq g_\sharp$ induced from a homotopy in $\mathsf{Top}$ $h:f\simeq g$.

Comment: You should really readjust your idea of «contrived»... :P

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez aww I was afraid of hearing that.. I wouldn't have guessed the chain homotopy, so I was hoping maybe there would be a more guessable homotopy in $\mathsf{Ch}\bullet$. Ah well :)

Comment: I don't know what Hatcher does, but the homotopies constructed in the book by Greenberg and Harper is quite nice (and does not really go through the simplicial set) I remember being marveled by that proof when I first read it an age ago!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Greenberg & Harper give the same proof as Dieck, and Rotman, inductively defining gradings of the chain homotopy. They also later give an explicit form via prism operators, which is Hatcher's approach. I haven't found any mention of homotopy in the sense of cylinder objects, which is what I'm looking for. Am I missing something?

Comment: (It is always a good idea to write in the question what you are looking for... !)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I edited my question. Should be clearer now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A homotopy in spaces is a map $I \times X \to Y$. The [Eilenberg-Zilber map](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Eilenberg-Zilber+map) can be used to induce from here a map $C_{\bullet}(I) \otimes C_{\bullet}(X) \to C_{\bullet}(Y)$. And with the right model of chains on the interval, this is the same thing as a chain homotopy.

There are ways to describe this construction without using chains or simplices, e.g. using the language of tensor (smash) products of spectra, but at some point you still need a theorem telling you how to actually compute stuff.

Comment: Would you say there's really no point in trying to circumvent the basic proof of the homotopy invariance of singular homology in that case? The only thing bugging me is the seemingly unpleasant explicit form of the chain homotopy, but maybe, as Mariano said, that's my problem.

Comment: @Exterior: I think there's no way to get around it. A priori a chain complex and a topological space are pretty different kinds of objects so it's not surprising that you have to do some work to relate them.